# How to add SUM() in Views

Tags: views

[image]

Like in the given picture

I would like to find and print the sum along with view results. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

Try the [Views Calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_calc) module

> This module adds simple calculations to a views table. Requires the Views module.
>
> You can SUM, AVERAGE, COUNT, MIN, MAX, or AVG selected columns. A plug in theme makes the view look more spreadsheet-like (right justifies numeric fields, shades calculated columns and rows, and underlines calculated rows).

Image from module page

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also "Use aggregation:". This link present in the advanced section of view.